# Extending Physijs.Mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, javascript-objects, physijs

I am working with Physijs to create a simple fps. Without Physijs I would create a Player object and use the code below to extend the `THREE.Mesh` class.

```
function Player() {
    THREE.Mesh.apply(this, arguments);
    ...
}
Player.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
```

Then I would instantiate a Player and add the camera to it for first person vision. However I would have to program all of the collision detection for Player so he wouldn't fall through the floor. I can use `new Physijs.BoxMesh`for the floor, but what about the player? How do I create a 'Player' class that has physics applied to it using Physijs? I tried something like... `Physijs.Mesh.apply(...)`... and `Object.create(Physijs.Mesh.prototype)`, but that doesn't work.

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do collision detection between meshes, all the meshes must be known to physi.js. In other words, you must use one of the physi.js shapes.

So you need a physi.js mesh for your Player so he doesn't fall through the floor. This doesn't have to be the same mesh that is visible to the user. You can have an invisible mesh that follows the player around and perhaps has a simpler geometry.

If you want anything more than one of the basic shapes (box, plane, sphere, etc) for your Physi.js mesh, yo'll need to build composite shapes.

Comment: Thank you for the response Bob! That clears up some confusion. If you don't mind me asking a follow up question... How would I add a camera to the Player object? Would I add it to the mesh?

In Player.js
`function Player() {
    this.bodyMesh = new Physijs.BoxMesh(...);
    ...
 }
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;`

Then I instantiate the Player in main.js...
`player = new Player();
 player.bodyMesh.add(camera);
 scene.add(player.bodyMesh);`

Comment: This should be posted as a separate question. And I don't fully understand it. Why would you add the camera to the player and not the scene? Do you want the camera to follow the player? There are several SO posts on how to do that.